# Grainy rendering in Cycles even with Render Samples at a high number

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Why do I have a Grainy rendering in Cycles even with Render Samples at 2000?
[image]

Comment: You screenshot is showing you are only using 32 samples, not 20000.

Comment: There is a difference between **preview samples** (viewport) and **render samples** (render output). I suspect you set the wrong value

Comment: I know but I set render to 20000 in samples

Comment: But you are only looking at it in the viewport not the render. Hit the render button, and wait a year for it to finish rendering :-)

Comment: Attach blend file?

Comment: @10Replies No need for a blend file here. The OP just doesn't understand that the viewport is not the only place to "render."

Comment: **pycoder** you right ! I did not hit the render button shame on me. Thank you all for your answers, the render will take 4 hours so I changed 20000 to 1000 :-)

Comment: I love these questions because I feel like this was the type of mistake that I made as a novice in blender 3 months ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up what everyone said, you are only looking in the viewport. The viewport has the 32 samples, but the render has 20000.

[image]

To see the render, hit the render button, but be warned that 20000 is a TON of samples (if you need that many samples, you're doing something wrong). A few hundred will do just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I see in the picture, you are using the render viewport and not actually rendering it with a camera. 
using the viewport and using the camera is totally different.

If you want to render with your camera you will want to press print ( or F12 ) on your keyboard.

The viewport render is only for a quick glance of what it will look like fully rendered with a ton of render samples ( your 20000) placed *into your camera.*

The viewport render which you are rendering in now will not produce a picture for you to save. The camera will.

The camera will render like you taking a picture in real life, but you must have samples for it to render without grain.